# How to prove this sequence doesn't converge to $0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $b_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers, and let $\displaystyle c_n=\frac{b_n}{1+b_n}$.
Prove that if $b_n$ is unbounded sequence, then $c_{n\:}$ doesn't converege to 0.

My approach:
We know that $A \Longrightarrow B \iff \neg B \Longrightarrow \neg A ~(*)$. So I will try to prove:
"If $c_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty $ , then $b_n$ is bounded."

So, we know that $c_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty $ :
$$
\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(c_n\right)= 0\:\Longrightarrow \:\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{b_n}{1+b_n}\right)=0
$$
$b_n,1$ are positive always so we can use limits arithmetic and get:
$$
\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(c_n\right)=0\:\Longrightarrow
\:\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{b_n}{1+b_n}\right)=0\:\Longrightarrow
 \:\frac{\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(b_n\right)}{\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(b_n+1\right)}=0\:\Longrightarrow
\:\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(b_n\right) = 0$$
Now, we see that $b_n$ converges, so it must be bounded sequence (no need to prove this).

And from $(*)$ I get : 
if $b_n$ is unbounded sequence, then $c_{n\:}$ doesn't converege to 0.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: No your proof is not correct. you can write $\:\frac{\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(b_n\right)}{\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(b_n+1\right)}=0$ only when the limits exist...that is when $b_n$ is a convergent sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is good, but the proof is invalid.

I'd use this technique, instead:
$$
c_n=1-\frac{1}{1+b_n}
$$

If $(c_n)\to0$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+b_n}=1
$$
so…

Comment: i'm not sure if i don't need to prove (from what you wrote) that $b_n\rightarrow 0$. there is a theorem that say so?

Comment: @user2637293 Since $b_n\to0$ it is bounded. Recall that if you know that $x_n\to l\ne0$, then $\frac{1}{x_n}\to\frac{1}{l}$.

Comment: Yes but, why $b_n→0$?

Comment: @user2637293 $1+b_n\to1$

Comment: Now i get that. tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof falls down where you've applied the algebraic limit theorem to sequences that may not converge. Perhaps try this.

If $\{b_n\}$ is unbounded then for every natural number $n$ there exists an $m_n$ such that $b_{m_n}>n$. Now consider the subsequence $\{c_{m_n}\}$. Clearly, 
$$c_{m_n}=\frac{b_{m_n}}{b_{m_n}+1}=1-\frac{1}{b_{m_n}+1}\to1.$$
Therefore, $\{c_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges to $1$. Therefore $\{c_n\}$ cannot converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$
\frac{b_n}{1+b_n} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+b_n}
$$

So, supposing $\{b_n\}$ is unbounded, it is not hard to show that the limit is $1$.